# video function in R video package doesn't work for mp4 file saved on local drive

Tags: r, video, shiny

I am trying to make a R Shiny dashboard that includes videos. I discovered the `video` package and its functions, `video`, `renderVideo`, and `videoOutput` and they work great provided the video I wish to display is on the internet. However, I want to display videos saved on my computer and I'm getting an error when I try.

Here is a minimal example.

The following code blocks works great.

```
library(shiny)
library(video)

ui <- fluidPage(
  videoOutput("ocean")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$ocean <- renderVideo(video("https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4"))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried saving the video at that hyperlink and putting it in the working directory as "oceans.mp4" but this code does **not** work:

```
library(shiny)
library(video)

ui <- fluidPage(
  videoOutput("ocean")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$ocean <- renderVideo(video("oceans.mp4"))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that I've tried a few other things, like using absolute path references and it all doesn't work.

The problem is with the `video::video` function --- it just doesn't seem to work on local files.

Any fixes?

Thank you, oh wise people of StackOverflow!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to put **oceans.mp4** in the **www** subfolder of the app folder. That is, create a folder **www** in your folder containing your app and put this file inside this folder.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are building a webpage, you need to have that image file accessible to the browser. Local files on your machine are not available by default. If you are using `runApp()` to launch your app, buy default the "www" folder will be shared as a top level folder. So create a "www" folder and move your image there. If you are running with `shinyApp` you need to create the resource path yourself. You can do

```
library(shiny)
library(video)

addResourcePath("vids", "www")

ui <- fluidPage(
  videoOutput("ocean")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$ocean <- renderVideo(video("vids/oceans.mp4"))
}

appObj <- shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)

runApp(appObj)
```

You don't have to use "www" if you use this method, you could name the folder whatever you want and share it with whatever prefix you like. Look at the documentation for `?addResourcePath`